# Two contractions with the same fixed point. Show that this sequence is convergent

Tags: convergence-divergence, fixed-point-theorems, sequence-of-function, contraction-mapping

We have $f,g:R\rightarrow R$ two contractions with the same fixed point and $(x_{n})_{n\geq1}$ a sequence with real numbers with the propriety that $x_{n+1}\in \left\{f(x_{n}),g(x_{n})\right\}$, for any $n\geq1$. Show that $(x_{n})_{n\geq1}$ is convergent.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: So if x_{n+1} = f(x_{n}) for every n or x_{n+1}=g(x_{n}) for every n the problem is clearly solved. The only case remains is when x_{n+1} is alternating between f(x_{n}) and g(x_{n}) and I feel we need to do this with subsequences but I dont have an exact idea for this.

Comment: Let $x = f(x) = g(x)$. You need to show that given $\varepsilon>0$, that you can choose $N$ so that $n\geq N$ implies  $d(x_n,x)<\varepsilon$. Using that $f(x_n)\to x$ and $g(x_n)\to x$, can you do so?

Comment: I will try thanks for the idea.